# pandas: resampling and computing the correct mean

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mean, resampling

I am using python's pandas but I do not know how to resample time series to 1-minute resolution and compute the mean value of each interval, using the trapezoid rule.

Suppose we are given the following time series in the file `data.csv`:

```
time_stamp,x
2000-01-01 00:00:00,0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:10,100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00,100.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00,200.0
```

Note that `x` value equals `100` for most of the first minute, so the answer

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00: 50.0,
2000-01-01 00:01:00: nan,
2000-01-01 00:02:00: 100.0,
2000-01-01 00:03:00: 200.0
```

obtained by

`pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col="time_stamp", parse_dates=["time_stamp"]).resample("1min").mean()`

is wrong. The correct mean value for the first minute would be `91.66666 = [(0 + 100) / 2 * 10s + 100 * 50s)] / 60s`. Similarly, the answer for the time interval `[2:00, 3:00]` should be `150`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your data is the unequal time step.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create your dataset
index = pd.date_range('2000/01/01  00:00:00', periods=4, freq='min').to_list()
index[1] = pd.Timestamp('2000/01/01  00:00:10')
values = [0., 100., 100., 200.]

data = pd.Series(values, index)
data

[Out]: 
2000-01-01 00:00:00      0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:10    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00    100.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00    200.0
```

When you call `.resample()` this is what's happening:

```
data.asfreq('T')
[Out]:
2000-01-01 00:00:00      0.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00      NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:00    100.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00    200.0
```

Values are placed into their corresponding minutes, as there is no data between 1min and 2min the value is filled with `NaN`. `.mean()` doesn't do anything useful (it turns the generator object into a df/series).

You could resample to 10 seconds, forward fill and then resample to 1 minute.

```
print(data.resample('10s').ffill())

[Out]:
2000-01-01 00:00:00      0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:10    100.0
2000-01-01 00:00:20    100.0
2000-01-01 00:00:30    100.0
2000-01-01 00:00:40    100.0
2000-01-01 00:00:50    100.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    100.0
2000-01-01 00:01:10    100.0
2000-01-01 00:01:20    100.0
2000-01-01 00:01:30    100.0
2000-01-01 00:01:40    100.0
2000-01-01 00:01:50    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:10    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:20    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:30    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:40    100.0
2000-01-01 00:02:50    100.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00    200.0

print(data.resample('10s').ffill().resample('1t').mean())
[Out]:
2000-01-01 00:00:00     83.333333
2000-01-01 00:01:00    100.000000
2000-01-01 00:02:00    100.000000
2000-01-01 00:03:00    200.000000
```

In your question you expect the result between 2min and 3min to be 150, but this will not be the case as you have value of 100 for the entirety of that minute.

Perhaps you'll find the `.interpolate(method='time')` useful. [Here's a link to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).